# Unable to display variable from apex into the visualforce pdf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to generate the pdf page and send an email , I have taken a variable in apex and displaying into the vf page  unfortunately its not printing on page when sending an email , let me know any ideas.

**Apex:**

```
public string fid {set;get;}
```

**VisualForce:**

```
<apex:page standardController="obj" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" renderAs="pdf">
   {!fid} 
</apex:page>
```

**Result:**

> Variable is not printing in pdf page.

Comment: Provide the functionality you are using that is proving a failure.

Comment: apex: public string fid {set;get;}     vf:  <apex:page standardController="obj"  showHeader="false"  standardStylesheets="false" renderAs="pdf">{!fid}  </apex:page>  variable is not printing in pdf page

Comment: maybe this can help http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/07/16/create-and-email-a-pdf-with-salesforce-com/

Comment: Do you ever set a value to your variable?

Comment: i can help you. But i need more information. You can use outputText tag. Your variable have some value???? please put your code for example retrieve somo value of the object. You should not have any problem to render this data as pdf. Pdf render have somo limitation check the saleforce documentation.

Comment: the values comes dynamically   from saved records

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include where this variable is set in your code? Preferability a complete and minimal example anyone would be able to set up in a developer org and have the same results.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this could be happening is that your VF page doesn't reference the controller extension class

**You have:**

```
<apex:page standardController="obj" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" renderAs="pdf">
 {!fid} 
</apex:page>
```

You need:

```
<apex:page standardController="obj" showHeader="false"
    extensions="MyController"
    standardStylesheets="false" renderAs="pdf">
 {!fid} 
</apex:page>
```

I'm surprised the  page even compiled.

If, on the other hand, this was a typo in your OP, then unless `fld` is populated by the extension class's constructor, when the page is rendered, the getter for `fld` will return null.  If you don;t want the constructor to do the population, then the getter itself has to do logic to populate itself.